# Best way to re-use javascript methods, error messages across Postman?

Tags: javascript, postman, newman

I have several functions that I'd like to replicate across different use cases in various requests and folders within the same collection (I'm using it as a template mostly, so it'll be pulling in variables externally)

There are many different suggestions in the Postman documentation but what's the best way to re-use code for such a use case?

Comment: I always find that what works best for each particular use case paradigm is usually the best way to do things

Answer (score 0):

I think generally the *best way* is to externalize the code into a library. You'll then make changes to the library and those changes will be reflected everywhere. Now there are [several ways to implement this method](https://blog.postman.com/adding-external-libraries-in-postman/), I'll leave with with the two that make sense for your use case:

**Load your library from a remote site**

If you are using some sort of development workflow that publishes your changes upstream, and you have your library published somewhere, you can load it at runtime:

```js
pm.sendRequest("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.0/dayjs.min.js", (err, res) => {
   //convert the response to text and save it as an environment variable
   pm.collectionVariables.set("dayjs_library", res.text());
 
   // eval will evaluate the JavaScript code and initialize the min.js
   eval(pm.collectionVariables.get("dayjs_library"));
 
   // you can call methods in the cdn file using this keyword
   let today = new Date();
   console.log("today=", today);
   console.log(this.dayjs(today).format())
})
```

**Store your code on a collection variable and load it that way**

A less pretty way to do it but more convenient to a lot of folks is just to drop the whole library into a collection variable like this:

[image]

Then you can load it when you need it:

```js
​​const dayjs_code = pm.collectionVariables.get('dayjs_code');
 
// Invoke an anonymous function to get access to the dayjs library methods
(new Function(dayjs_code))();
 
let today = new Date();
console.log(dayjs(today).format())
```

In both cases when you update your library you either have to republish it or copy paste again to the collection variable. However that surely beats copy pasting a piece of code to 20 odd places and figuring out what's updated, what's not and fighting bugs while at it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll explorer this further...

Comment: Is it not possible to simply put all the functions in the parent pre-request script?

Comment: I guess you could, but then you can only re-use those scripts in one folder. What about the next collection, etc. It all depends on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

What I've been doing lately is adding functions to my collection level pre-request script like so

```
collectionUtils = {
    clearEnvData: function (pm) {
        some useful code
    },
    // called after every request to ensure server coverage durring smoke testing.
    cycleCurrentServer: function (serverCount, pm) {
        some useful code
    }
}
```

Then wherever I want to use these methods I do something like this

```
collectionUtils.cycleCurrentServer(index, pm);
```

Comment: But what if certain pm or postman methods are not supported internally when calling functions?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question, but I do have to pass pm into the function when I call it at the request level.

Comment: Understood. But things like this don't work:
```
var notice = "Invalid response"
tests[notice] = true
```